# Why is import axios for web worker not working?

Tags: reactjs, web-worker

I am attempting to create an API request with web worker using axios, here is my worker.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default () => {
    self.addEventListener('message', e => {
        if (!e) return;
        let config = e.data;
        let url = config.url;
        let params = config.params;
        setInterval(()=>{
            axios.get(url,{params}).then(res=>{
                postMessage(res);
            })
        },5000);
    });
}
```

The only thing that being weird is axios is not defined, what am i doing wrong?

here the snippet of my webworker codes

```
export default class MonitoringWorker {
    constructor(worker) {
        const code = worker.toString();
        const blob = new Blob(['(' + code + ')()']);
        return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
}

import worker from './worker/worker'
import MonitoringWorker from './worker/MonitoringWorker'

    export default class TransactionMonitoring extends Component{
        componentDidMount(){
            console.log({worker})
            this.worker = new MonitoringWorker(worker);
            this.worker.addEventListener('message', e => {
                console.log("RECEIVED DATA",e.data);
            });
            this.worker.postMessage({ url:'xxxx'})
        }
       //restOfcode
    }
```

Comment: First of all, do you have axios installed, right? `npm install axios --save`

Comment: yes, in another component axios working well, it's already installed

Comment: Have you tried to import axios on your main **.js** file as well? Not only on the modules, but also where you call the modules

Comment: doesn't it will be overkilled?

Comment: How have you setup or configured your web-worker

Comment: all code have been posted on my question @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto I am not talking about the way you are using it but how you have set it up in webpack. Are you using `worker-loader`. Have you configured your worker to allow `es6 imports`

Comment: no, i dont set something like that, how should i configure the worker so it allows import?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `importScripts`

```
importScripts("https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js");
```

At the top of your worker file.